# Connecting 3 tables in MySQL to select field

Tags: mysql

i have database structure like image below

[image]

i want to select all the subdistricts, with subdistricts name, cities name and, provinces name. my code goes like this:

```
SELECT province.name as province, city.name as city, subdistrict.name as subdistrict 
    from provinces province, cities city, subdistricts subdistrict 
    WHERE province.id = city.id AND city.id = subdistrict.id;
```

but i only got as much as the total of provinces data not all the subdistricts data

Answer (score 0):

You basic SQL is missing a comma, but generally should work. I would strongly suggest using more modern join syntax:-

```
SELECT province.name AS province, 
        city.name AS city, 
        subdistrict.name AS subdistrict 
FROM provinces province
INNER JOIN cities city
ON province.id = city.id 
INNER JOIN subdistricts subdistrict 
ON city.id = subdistrict.id;
```

However, from you description I am unsure if you are trying to do some aggregate processing?

Comment: `SELECT province.name AS province, 
        city.name AS city, 
        subdistrict.name AS subdistrict 
FROM provinces province
INNER JOIN cities city
ON province.id = city.province_id 
INNER JOIN subdistricts subdistrict 
ON city.id = subdistrict.city_id;` thats the right one